# D3.js - Select similar shapes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to select elements with a similar shapes from an svg element with **D3.js** for my next project.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create a new `g` group with all the selected shapes (which, in the example below, are all the ports of the switch stencil). Using a svg editor like Inkscape (but also Illustrator, Gravit, Figma, Vectr)I can select the shape I'm interested to and with a right click select all the same shapes into the document:

#### Inkscape

`right click --> select same --> fill and stroke`

[image: Select same shapes from inkscape]

[image: Result]

#### Figma

`edit --> select all with same style`

[image: Select same shapes with Figma]

[image: Results]

Probably, this is not even the right way to select similar shapes. Indeed, I have some doubts about the "same stroke and fill" stuff and I'd like to find a more clever way to select those.

I have no idea on how **D3.js** can help me to automate this process and I'm stucked here:

```
// Import the external svg
d3.xml("3650.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function (error, xml) {
            if (error) throw error;

    // Select the svg node
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);

    // Append it to the document
    document.appendChild(importedNode.cloneNode(true));

    // Select all the same shapes
    d3.selectAll( some magic to make it happen )
}
```

I'm asking to expert users to help me to make this happen.
I'm also open to other ways to achieve this if it is not possible with **D3.js** (hope @mbostock awesome work is what I need here, because I'm really in love with it).

Thanks!

Comment: "I have some doubts about the "same stroke and fill" stuff and I'd like to find a more clever way to select those." What do you have in mind? :)

Comment: Well, I'd like a holy features like "Select all the ports in this switch" but I can be satisfied even with a "Select all the shapes with the same shape" ;)

Comment: *"same shape"* is too broad. However, you can easily select all the elements with the same **attributes** (fill, stroke, etc...), using a getter and a filter.

Comment: Even if in the example above, when I was showing the Inkscape procedure, I'm selecting all the shapes with the same "fill and stroke", I was wondering if a filter could be applied using a recurrent `path`.